# Получение значений из связанных таблиц

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql

Дано: N разных таблиц, у которых есть одна общая черта - у всех есть столбце со значением, ссылающимся на значения другой таблицы. Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы не писать запросы с join-ами для каждой таблицы, а получать имя таблицы и поля в этой таблицы, на которую ссылается основная таблица и уже на основании этих данных формировать запрос по одному шаблону для всех таблиц? И если можно, то как? Спасибо.

Comment: А кто мешает?

Comment: Поправил вопрос:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные о внешних ключах хранятся в системном представлении [`sys.foreign_key_columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186306.aspx)

Как составить запрос на получение списка внешних ключей из метаданных можно почитать тут: [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005). И на основе полученных данных о столбцах и ссылающихся таблицах динамически формировать запрос с JOIN-ами.

Comment: Про таблицу я уже нашел. А за ссылку спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя. Чем вас не устраивает использование JOIN'ов?

Comment: Да просто хотелось, так сказать, красивое решение сделать, подходящее для всех таблиц.

Comment: JOIN - это красивое решение, подходящее для всех таблиц :)

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос: как получить список внешних ключей таблицы и определить на какую таблицу они ссылаются?

Comment: @minamoto (Это из сейлормун?) Можно, можно. Только вместо одного запроса с одним recordset'ом в результате вы получаете 1 запрос для главной таблицы и n (количество подчинённых) x m (количество значений ключевого поля) для подчинённых. И работа, которую на себя брал бы sqlserver отдаётся клиенту (чтоб служба мёдом не казалась). Вопрос тут один: зачем?

Comment: Просто если делать в лоб, то придется писать для каждой и N таблиц свой запрос. А я хотел бы сделать так:
1) Перебираю все таблицы
2) Определяю ее внешние ключи
3) Формирую запрос и получаю данные в "красивом" виде, где в столбцах ссылок стоят не ID записей таблицы на которую этот столбец сссылается, а значение соответсвующее этому ID
Как то так:) 
С получением списка внешних ключей вроде разобрался. Буду дальше копать, но если у кого есть предложения по реализации, буду очень признателен

Comment: Извините, тогда JOIN'ы. Сервер, как я понимаю, mssql. Как там отыскивать иностранные ключи, я не знаю, да и не интересно. А далее -- формируете sql-запрос (какой кучерявый select получится -- вопрос другой), выполняете и получаете то, что запросили.